# My gradle spring project on intellij taking too long to refresh

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using Intellij IDEA 2017.1.4. I am new to gradle. I have been given a multi modular spring project on Gradle. Problem is when I do **"Refresh all gradle projects"** *(on the side pan of IDEA)*, it takes hours. Some times a day. It is necessary for me sometimes doing refresh due to addition of dependencies or something else.

Following is my root **build.gradle** file. Please help.

```
group 'tv.videoready'
version = "1.0.0-RELEASE"
description = "Mobile/Web API's Application"

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("gradle.plugin.com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties:gradle-git-properties:1.4.17")
    }

}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties"

jar {
    baseName = 'rest-api'
    version = '1.0.0-RELEASE'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://artifactory.videoready.tv/artifactory/libs-release-local' }
    maven { url 'http://artifactory.videoready.tv/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local' }
}

gitProperties {
    dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
    dateFormatTimeZone = "UTC"
    gitRepositoryRoot = new File("${project.rootDir}")
    gitPropertiesDir = new File("${project.rootDir}/src/main/resources")
}

ext {
    springBootVersion = "1.4.0.RELEASE"
    mysqlConnectorVersion = '5.1.39'
    swaggerVersion = '2.7.0'
}

dependencies {
    // Actuator
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
    compile 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.20.0.RELEASE'

    compile project(":login")
    compile project(":config")
    compile project(":device")
    compile project(":password")
    compile project(":sms")
    compile project(":remote-record")
    compile project(":otp")
    compile project(":profile")

    compile("de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:1.4.4")
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://artifactory.videoready.tv/artifactory/libs-release-local' }
        maven { url 'http://artifactory.videoready.tv/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local' }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:${springBootVersion}")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:${springBootVersion}")

        compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysqlConnectorVersion}")
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '4.3.2.Final'

        //HTTP Client
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.5'
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2'

        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'module-logger', version: '2.0.2-RELEASE')
        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'cors-filter', version: '1.0.0')



//        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'common-sql-domains', version: '1.5.8-SNAPSHOT')
    compile files("/home/divya/projects/tatasky/common-services/common-sql-domains/build/libs/    common-sql-domains-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar")
        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'mm-domains', version: '3.1.4-SNAPSHOT')
        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'common-constants', version: '1.4.10-SNAPSHOT')

        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'domain-pojo-utils', version: '1.2.0-SNAPSHOT')
        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'validation-util', version: '1.2.0-SNAPSHOT')

        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'search-client', version: '1.4.4-SNAPSHOT'){
            exclude(group: 'tv.videoready', module: 'common-constants')
            exclude(group: 'tv.videoready', module: 'common-sql-domains')
            exclude(group: 'tv.videoready', module: 'mm-domains')
        }
        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'common-pojo', version: '1.3.23-SNAPSHOT')

        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'i-spy-client', version: '1.0.2-SNAPSHOT')
        compile(group: 'tv.videoready', name: 'cache', version: '2.0.26-SNAPSHOT')
        compile('com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.7.5')
        compile('com.hazelcast:hazelcast-client:3.7.5')
        compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${swaggerVersion}")
        compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${swaggerVersion}")
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude module: ("spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
        compile.exclude module: ("spring-boot-starter-logging")
    }

    sourceSets.main.resources {
        srcDir '../src/main/resources'
    }
}

subprojects {
    group = 'tv.videoready'
    version = '1.0.0-RELEASE'
}

processResources {
    filesMatching("**/application.properties") {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}

bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
    systemProperty "log4j.configurationFactory", "tv.videoready.logger.LoggingConfigurationFactory"
    systemProperty "mockRRM", true
    systemProperty "dev.hazelcast.setup.enabled", "false"
    systemProperty "dev.hazelcast.cluster.group.password", "hari"
    systemProperty "hazelcast.cluster.group.password", "hari"
    systemProperty "spring.config.location", "classpath:hazelcast-dev.properties"
    systemProperty "jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false"
}
```

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593535/guidelines-for-splitting-up-a-very-large-gradle-project-with-lots-of-sub-project/42644503#42644503. See there for some suggestions on how to improve performance.

Comment: Does the command line Gradle build take the same time?

Comment: @CrazyCoder No, command line build is faster than the IDEA's refresh all gradle projects.