# Run specific project using gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a Groovy application, I am using Gradle as my build tool. I have 2 seperate projects a Ratpack project with it's own build.gradle file and then a React project with it's own build.gradle file.

When I do ./gradlew run It builds my Ratpack project which in my Ratpacks build.gradle file has

```
compile project(':react-app')
```

In the dependencies closure.

Is there a way to just be able to run one of the projects for example ./gradlew runRatPack which stops the React project from being built?

Comment: You might find this topi helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272344/gradle-exclude-a-specific-subproject-from-full-build

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the following line
compile project(':react-app') which states there is a Project Dependency to
compile name : 'react-app' - artifact dependency, then the project will try to pick the artifact from the repository instead of building the project.
Please let me know if the issue is addressed and this solves your issue.