# Gradle disable the build of dependency projects

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a a multi-project gradle project (Android) with following structure:

```
root
|-projA
|-projB
|-projC
|-...
```

In my specific case, `projA` is an app which uses `projB` (module). When I run `build` on `projA`, `projB` also gets built. I need to perform an action only on the project that was originally built (the project where the original action was performed on).

For this purpose I need to somehow get the name/path of this project. I need to do this in the `afterEvaluate` step if this matters.

**Example:**

```
gradlew :projA:build   // Builds A and B     ->  I want only "projA"
gradlew :projB:build   // Builds B           ->  I want "projB"
gradlew :projC:build   // Builds A, B and C  ->  I want only "projC"
```

I am not sure how I can achive this, I hope someone of you can help me.

Comment: May you will find it helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272344/gradle-exclude-a-specific-subproject-from-full-build ?

Answer (score 5):

You can check the [official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html):

> The standard project dependencies are supported and makes relevant projects configured. **If project A has a compile dependency on project B then building A causes configuration of both projects.**

However you can disable the build of dependency projects (but pay attention!)

> If you don't want depended on projects to be built when doing a partial build. To disable the build of the depended on projects **you can run Gradle with the -a option.**

Example:

```
gradle -a :projA:build
```

[From the doc:](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html)

```
-a, --no-rebuild
```

Do not rebuild project dependencies.